# Shorten useless coding?

Tags: php, steam-web-api, garrys-mod

Creating my loading screen on garrys mod, and seeing this "useless" coding, and was betting that there is a way to shorten it massively, however I am quite a php nooby and was wondering if there was a perhaps a way to use arrays or something to make it easier/shorter? [Code Here](http://pastebin.com/B92w4qUM)

Comment: I do recommend you to at least put all the cases where $map = " "; in a comment for later reference.

Comment: Consider a `switch` statement. All the `$map = " ";` lines can be part of the `default` `case`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$array = array(
   "gm_flatgrass" => "Flatgrass",
   "cs_assault" => "CS Assault",
   "de_train" => "",
   ...
);

$getmap = $_GET['mapname'];

if(array_key_exists($getmap,$array)) {
    $map =  $array[$getmap];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, using 1 line per map instead of 3 <3